# what is wrong in this query? for infinidb

Tags: infinidb

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
  a.ID ID,
  a.callingparty callingparty,
  a.calledparty calledparty,
  str_to_date(a.starttime, '%Y-%m-%d %T') starttime,
  b.calltype,
  a.DURATION,
  a.SERVERNAME,
  a.CHANNEL,
  a.EONENAME
FROM crimes.mms_cri a
LEFT OUTER JOIN crimes.mms_calltype_master b
  ON a.calltype = b.idd
WHERE (a.calledparty = '9934024552'
AND a.callingparty = '500'

AND a.starttime >= '2014-01-27 06:00:00'
AND a.starttime <= '2015-12-27 20:59:59'
)
OR (a.callingparty = '9934024552'
AND a.calledparty = '500'

AND a.starttime >= '2014-01-27 06:00:00'
AND a.starttime <= '2015-12-27 20:59:59')
AND a.calledparty IS NOT NULL
AND a.callingparty IS NOT NULL;
```

> Error Code: 138. The syntax or the data type(s) is not supported by InfiniDB. Please check the InfiniDB syntax guide for supported syntax or data types.